# What's the difference between "voivodship" and "voivodeship" (noun)?

Tags: word-usage

I am especially referring to voivod(e)ship ("województwo") in Poland.
Are these forms interchangeable? 
I've noticed a different software developer used voivodeship while I used voivodship for an address form on the webpage

Comment: It looks as if they are simply [variant spellings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voivodeship#Terminology) of the same word.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about Polish.

Comment: Though the word "voivodeship" (other spellings are "voievodship" and "voivodship") appears in English dictionaries such as the OED and Webster's, it is not in common general usage, and voivodeships in Poland and elsewhere are frequently referred to as "provinces".

Comment: First thing I see is that the second one has an ‘e’ in it.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey whether it is spelled "voivodship " or "voivodeship ," it is certainly not a Polish word.  As you can see from the question, the corresponding Polish word is "województwo."

Comment: The spelling with "ode" is to indicate it is a long vowel /oʊd/, rather than a short vowel. The [Wikipedia page already linked](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voivodeship) has the relevant information on its version in various languages - it's not just a Polish term but no version has an /e/ or anything similar pronounced after the /d/. Both spellings exist, but you should certainly standardise on one within an organisation or publication.

Answer (score 2):

While I agree this question is not in common usage in English I am not 100% sure voivodship exist or existed in other countries and then how do we write in English in historical books or write about nowadays Poland?

Voivodship refers also to Polish-Lithuanian Commonwealth (historical context) and might (this is my suspection) to other slavic countries in the past.

Quoting wikipedia:
"Words for "voivodeship" in various languages include the Polish: województwo; the Romanian: voievodat; the Bulgarian: voivoda (войвода); the Serbian: vojvodina (војводина), vojvodstvo (војводство) or vojvodovina (војводовина); the Hungarian: vajdaság; the Belarusian: ваяводства (vajаvodstva); the Lithuanian: vaivadija. Some of these words, or variants of them, may also be used in English."
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voivodeship

Let's finish discussion agreeing that there are multiple spellings in english for the same word

Answer (score -1):

With all respect to Mr. Harvey, voivodeship/voivodship is a word - it's the English translation of the Polish word wojewódstwo, an administrative district (sometimes translated as 'province'.) For translators of historical or geographical materials, it is an important word and for those of us who like to maintain a high standard in our translation work, it is an issue of importance, also illustrated by the fact that a Polish government commission on standardizing English translations of Polish geographical terms/names brought this topic up. https://www.gov.pl/web/ksng/wykaz-angielskich-nazw-wazniejszych-obiektow-geograficznych-polozonych-na-terytorium-rzeczypospolitej-polskiej (scroll down for the English pdf file.)(They think it should be voivodship - are they right? I am not yet sure.)
Also, those who do translation in these regions will know that 'oblast' is used in English when translating a similar concept from Russia. Unfortunately however, I have not found any answers here. When I do, I shall return and post them.

Comment: I would have thought that the spelling from the Polish government commission should be used, at least when discussing Poland. Why do you object to it?

Comment: I object to it because it follows Polish pronunciation rules-not English.' Vod' is not pronounced the same way in English as 'vode' ('e' at the end lengthens the 'o' preceding it.) A Pole reading 'voivodship' would pronounce it correctly b/c of their rules (and incorrectly pronounce 'voivodeship' because they pronounce everything they see - 'vo-y-vode-y-shyp'). An English form of the word, used for English speakers - should we not use English rules? (And come to Poland and hear how Poles, even English teachers, pronounce 'vegetables'. Hair-raising.)